# Does the OneLogin ruby-saml gem support IdP initiated sign in?

Tags: onelogin

It isn't clear from the README, but this issue seems to suggest it does. I'm just looking for clarification https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml/issues/272

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the [ruby-saml](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml) gem supports IdP-initiated SSO.

The unique difference while coding with the SP-initiated SSO is that you can store the ID of the AuthNRequest sent to the IdP, in order to later validate the InResponseTo value of the SAMLResponse.

Review this example to see [how code an ACS](https://github.com/onelogin/ruby-saml-example/blob/master/app/controllers/saml_controller.rb#L20) (Assertion Consumer Service) endpoint